# In Storybook, argTypes produces an error after converting ComponentMeta to Meta. (As parts of migration to V7)

Tags: storybook

I updated storybook v6 to v7.

Then, I have to change statements deprecated.
So, I change like below↓

```
export default {
  title: 'Input',
  component: Input,
  argTypes: InputDoc,
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Input>;
```

↓

```
const meta: Meta<typeof Input> = {
  title: 'Input',
  component: Input,
  argTypes: InputDoc,
};
export default meta;
```

---

Then, an error occurred on argTypes!

```
Type '{ type: { name: string; type: string; defaultValue: string; description: string; table: { type: { summary: string; }; defaultValue: { summary: string; }; }; control: { type: string; options: string[]; }; }; error: { ...; }; ... 4 more ...; onChange: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<ArgTypes<InputProps>>'.
  The types of 'type.type' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"string" | "number" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "function" | SBType | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

The reasons of the error is the InputDoc.
InputDoc definition is it.

```
export const InputDoc = {
  type: {
    name: 'Input',
    type: 'string',
    defaultValue: 'text',
    description: '入力タイプ',
    table: {
      type: { summary: typeList.join(' | ') },
      defaultValue: { summary: 'text' },
    },
    control: {
      type: 'select',
      options: typeList,
    },
  },
  error: {
    name: 'error',
    type: 'string',
    defaultValue: '',
    description: 'エラー時のメッセージ',
    table: {
      type: { summary: 'string' },
      defaultValue: { summary: '' },
    },
    control: {
      type: 'text',
    },
  },
  disabled: {
    name: 'disabled',
    type: 'boolean',
    defaultValue: false,
    description: 'disabled',
    table: {
      type: { summary: 'boolean' },
      defaultValue: { summary: 'false' },
    },
  },
  required: {
    name: 'required',
    type: 'boolean',
    defaultValue: false,
    description: 'required',
    table: {
      type: { summary: 'boolean' },
      defaultValue: { summary: 'false' },
    },
  },
  label: {
    name: 'label',
    type: 'string',
    defaultValue: '',
    description: 'ラベル',
    table: {
      type: { summary: 'string' },
      defaultValue: { summary: '' },
    },
    control: {
      type: 'text',
    },
  },
  placeholder: {
    name: 'placeholder',
    type: 'string',
    defaultValue: 'placeholder',
    description: 'プレースホルダー',
    table: {
      type: { summary: 'string' },
      defaultValue: { summary: '' },
    },
    control: {
      type: 'text',
    },
  },
  onChange: {
    name: 'onChange',
    type: 'function',
    defaultValue: '',
    description: 'onChange',
    table: {
      type: { summary: 'function' },
      defaultValue: { summary: '' },
    },
    control: {
      type: 'text',
    },
  },
};
```

1. When I make InputDoc as below, an error disappear.
   So reasons of the error is definitely InputDoc.

```
export const InputDoc = {
  type: {
    name: 'Input',
  },
};
```

2. I try below form, but a situation wasn't changed.

```
export const InputDoc = {
  type: {
    name: 'Input',
    type: { name: 'string' },
    defaultValue: 'text',
    description: '入力タイプ',
    table: {
      type: { summary: typeList.join(' | ') },
      defaultValue: { summary: 'text' },
    },
    control: {
      type: 'select',
      options: typeList,
    },
  },
  error: {
    name: 'error',
    type: { name: 'string' },
    defaultValue: '',
    description: 'エラー時のメッセージ',
    table: {
      type: { summary: 'string' },
      defaultValue: { summary: '' },
    },
    control: {
      type: 'text',
    },
  },
  disabled: {
    name: 'disabled',
    type: { name: 'boolean' },
    defaultValue: false,
    description: 'disabled',
    table: {
      type: { summary: 'boolean' },
      defaultValue: { summary: 'false' },
    },
  },
  required: {
    name: 'required',
    type: { name: 'boolean' },
    defaultValue: false,
    description: 'required',
    table: {
      type: { summary: 'boolean' },
      defaultValue: { summary: 'false' },
    },
  },
  label: {
    name: 'label',
    type: { name: 'string' },
    defaultValue: '',
    description: 'ラベル',
    table: {
      type: { summary: 'string' },
      defaultValue: { summary: '' },
    },
    control: {
      type: 'text',
    },
  },
  placeholder: {
    name: 'placeholder',
    type: { name: 'string' },
    defaultValue: 'placeholder',
    description: 'プレースホルダー',
    table: {
      type: { summary: 'string' },
      defaultValue: { summary: 'placeholder' },
    },
    control: {
      type: 'text',
    },
  },
  onChange: {
    name: 'onChange',
    type: { name: 'function' },
    defaultValue: '',
    description: 'onChange',
    table: {
      type: { summary: 'function' },
      defaultValue: { summary: '' },
    },
    control: {
      type: 'text',
    },
  },
};
```

I'm junior developer. I have to solve it as soon as.

Please help me hero.